# Searching for keywords in python

Tags: python, list, keyword

If i ask a question in python and the answer is a sentence such as "There's water in my phone", how can i make the program detect the word "water" or "phone" and print a solution such as "Dry your phone"?.

```
similar_words = ["water","damaged","wet","soaked","battery"]

words = input("Enter a word or sentence: ").strip().split()

for word in words:

if word.lower() in similar_words:

           print ("Go to a mechanic")


else:    

     print ("sorry your answer doesn't match the criteria, please try again")
```

this is what iv'e done so far but when i answer the question in a sentence i get the solution which i want which is "Go to the mechanic", im a newbie so please be bare with my stupidity.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by the question, the answer ranges from utterly trivial to impossible given the current state of AI. You need to provide more details, including code that you have written to try to solve your problem.

Comment: It's called natural language processing, and the answers would be way too big for this site.

Comment: I don't have the code on me but ill try to replicate it and i thought that there would be a function on this but there isn't. I'm pretty sure that it is not natural language, it has to be basic python, im a newbie.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What @polku means is that what you are trying to do is Natural Language Processing - i.e. you are trying to interpret normal spoke language. It is incredibly difficult to do - yes you can do it in Python, but it isn't 'newbie' level - it requires a lot of clever techniques do with syntax analysis and semantic analysis of the input. If you want something very basic - then - your program won't ever produce 'Dry your phone' - as that doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: If you have a fixed list of words and a dictionary with canned responses keyed to those words, it is easy enough to split a string into a list of words and then loop through dictionary keys , testing them against the list of words by appropriate use of the `in` operator (or perhaps using set operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple - basic solution :

```
words = input("Enter a word or sentence: ").strip()
words = words.lower()
if 'water' in words and 'phone' in words:
    print('Dry your phone')
```

That exactly matches your 'problem description', but will of course also generate the same message if you input the following :

- There is no water in my phone
- I didn't get water in my phone
- There is a phone in my bath water

and it will completely ignore :

- I think I got my phone wet.

Just remember - this solution doesn't scale well (as you try to 'understand' more sentences the code gets complex very quickly), it doesn't understand common variants or negatives, or synonyms.

This isn't really any form of AI - you could just as easily look for particular numbers rather than words.

To get a computer to really 'understand' what you mean - so it knows that 'to get wet' is similar to 'get water on', and requires the same answer, or recognises 'didn't get water on' as a negative for instance - is a whole other ball game

Comment: This really helped i appreciate